# SSIS - Killing Excel.exe when data flow task fails

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, ssis

How can I kill the excel.exe process in SSIS during the data flow task when it fails?  There could be multiple instances of Excel.exe running from other packages that are perfectly valid so I don't want to loop through all instances killing them.

My problem is that during the data flow task the process will sometimes fail due to a sheet that is named incorrectly or missing columns.  This keeps an instance of excel.exe running which is now an orphan task eating up resources so it needs to be killed.

At the same time there are other SSIS packages running that are accessing their own excel.exe process and aren't having any issues.

So how can I kill the orphan excel.exe process without impacting the other excel.exe process?

Thanks

Comment: what is your exact problem? to kill or not to kill or whom to kill? Please, rephrase your question, and make more clear what you're trying to do and what problem you're finding.

Comment: It sounds like you have SSIS starting an Excel process, failing, and the process keeps running?  [Here's](http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/?p=82) someone's code for how they kept track of their Excel instance.

Comment: @Russell your link is during the script task which I can use to get the process id, not the data flow task where it opens the connection to excel via the connection manager.  No code is involved.

Comment: I must be missing something in your scenario. I created a package with 2008 and added an Excel Connection Manager. I set delay validation to true for everything, bumped my MaximumErrorCount up to 200 and dropped a dataflow on with Excel source to a script task that fires a messagebox (poor man's breakpoint). I then spun up a PowerShell script looking for a process named Excel. Whether the package execution failed (bad sheet name) or succeeded the PowerShell script never registered Excel process firing up. Are you instantiating Excel via the COM model?

Comment: Were you able to fix it ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @bala Sort of. Excel is meant to be ran from the client side due to all the user messages that potentially pop. I ended up converting all my Excel files to CSV with the ACE.OLEDB driver to automate processing. Add the following to a script task to kill Excel: Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer and then GetWindowThreadProcessId(New IntPtr(objExcel.Hwnd), ExcelPID)
If ExcelPID > 0 Then
 Dim ExcelProc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(ExcelPID)
 If ExcelProc IsNot Nothing Then ExcelProc.Kill()
End If

Answer (score 0):

you can stop a windows service with the following script

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim controller As New ServiceController
    controller.MachineName = "."
    controller.ServiceName = "ReportServer"

    Dim status As String = controller.Status.ToString

    If status.ToLower = "running" Then
        controller.Stop()
    End If

    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
```

there is the Finalize method on the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) Class. Maybe it can kill a process.

Comment: I don't want to kill the wrong excel.exe.  There may be 5 excel.exe processes running and only one is an orphan.  This could kill the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you'll need to get the host machine's processID from sysprocesses and run taskkill to get rid of the process.  Something like this in TSQL:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @cmd = 'taskkill /pid ' + 
    CAST(hostprocess AS VARCHAR(10)) 
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE program_name = 'Microsoft® Excel'
AND status = 'sleeping'

xp_CmdShell (@cmd);
```

It would be better if you can immediately get the SPID of the Excel process immediately when it's spawned, then you can just store it and plug that into the command above.  Read up on the [taskkill](http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm) function because it has a few other options that might be useful.